# Secondary Tile "snapping" back to the image it was created with

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, tile

I have a secondary tile which uses ShellTileSchedule to update itself.

The user can turn off that behavior in settings. At which point, I revert the secondary tile to be the background.png (I also stop the relevant ShellTileSchedule by calling .Stop on it).

```
tile.Update(new StandardTileData() { BackgroundImage = new Uri("Background.png", UriKind.Relative) });
```

Now, when I update the setting and this code gets executed, the secondary tile actually shows the correct image for about 10 seconds, but then it "snaps back" to the image it was originally created with.

I am running very similar code on the primary tile, and it works perfectly well there.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Edit: Even if I initialize the tile to Background.png initially, the tile will snap back to the remote URI once that's set up.

Comment: Is this only the case in the emulator or even if you debug your app on a real device?

Comment: @TorbenSchramme: I am a moron.. See below... Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I am a moron.

Had another code path that was nuking the tile back to the remote uri. Duh.